# Parse json url in ajax/javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, jsonp

I am trying to create an ajax request that will call json URL, parse it and then for each URL attribute (in this json) will execute json request for this attribute and then bring me back the version field and id.

This is the code that I've written:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
          url:'http://build-20003.eu1.kokol.com:8080/job/ios_sdk/api/json?pretty=true&tree=builds[*]',
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {'authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('elior:3cbe5b03748e8f3f800e')}
        }).done(function(data) {
                var arrParent = JSON.parse(data);                               
                var i;
                var j;
                for(j = 0; j < arrParent.length; j++) {
                        $.ajax({
                          url:data.build[j].url,
                          method: 'GET',
                          headers: {'authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('elior:3cbe5b03748e8f3f800e')}
                        }).done(function(datajob) {
                                var arr = JSON.parse();
                                for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                                        out += "<tr><td>" +
                                        arr[i].number +
                                        "</td><td>" +
                                        arr[i].version +
                                        "</td><td>" +
                                        arr[i].timestamp +
                                        "</td></tr>";
                                }                               
                        });
                }
                document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
                })
});     
</script>
```

This is example of the first json URL:

```
    {
  "builds" : [
    {
      "actions" : [
        {
          
        },
        {
          
        },
        {
          
        },
        {
          
        },
        {
          
        },
        {
          
        }
      ],
      "artifacts" : [
        
      ],
      "building" : false,
      "description" : null,
      "duration" : 32640,
      "estimatedDuration" : 33113,
      "executor" : null,
      "fullDisplayName" : "ios_sdk #282",
      "id" : "2016-06-20_09-32-23",
      "keepLog" : false,
      "number" : 282,
      "result" : "SUCCESS",
      "timestamp" : 1466415143000,
      "url" : "http://build-20003.eu1.kolko.com:8080/job/ios_sdk/282/",
      "builtOn" : "macmini12",
      "changeSet" : {
        
      },
      "culprits" : [
```

This is an example of the second json URL (from the above):

```
    {
  "actions" : [
    {
      "parameters" : [
        {
          "name" : "Version",
          "value" : "5.0.1"
        },
        {
          "name" : "IOS",
          "value" : true
        },
        {
          "name" : "CocoaPods",
          "value" : false
        },
        {
          "name" : "Unity",
          "value" : false
        },
        {
          "name" : "Publish",
          "value" : false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "causes" : [
        {
          "shortDescription" : "Started by user elior",
          "userId" : "elior",
          "userName" : "elior"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      
    },
    {
      "buildsByBranchName" : {
        "refs/remotes/origin/master" : {
          "buildNumber" : 282,
          "buildResult" : null,
          "marked" : {
            "SHA1" : "4e3b7d0199aaa9b8d6cebcf8ccd6b2a5",
            "branch" : [
              {
                "SHA1" : "4e3b7d0199aaa9b8d6cebcf8ccd6b2a5",
                "name" : "refs/remotes/origin/master"
              }
            ]
          },
          "revision" : {
            "SHA1" : "4e3b7d29ddaaa9b8b0cebcf8ccd6b2a5",
            "branch" : [
              {
                "SHA1" : "4e3b7d019929b0cbd6cebcf8ccd6b2a5",
                "name" : "refs/remotes/origin/master"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "lastBuiltRevision" : {
        "SHA1" : "4e3b7d019929ddb8b0cbd6cebcf82a5",
        "branch" : [
          {
            "SHA1" : "4e3b7d019929ddaaa9ebcf8ccd6b2a5",
            "name" : "refs/remotes/origin/master"
          }
        ]
      },
      "remoteUrls" : [
        "https://deployment:username@bitbucket.org/kokol/kokol.sdk.ios.git"
      ],
      "scmName" : ""
    },
    {
      
    },
    {
      
    }
  ],
  "artifacts" : [
    
  ],
  "building" : false,
  "description" : null,
  "duration" : 32640,
  "estimatedDuration" : 33113,
  "executor" : null,
  "fullDisplayName" : "ios_sdk #282",
  "id" : "2016-06-20_09-32-23",
  "keepLog" : false,
  "number" : 282,
  "result" : "SUCCESS",
  "timestamp" : 1466415143000,
  "url" : "http://build-20003.eu1.kokol.com:8080/job/ios_sdk/282/",
  "builtOn" : "macmini12",
  "changeSet" : {
    "items" : [
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Have you tried an introductory Ajax tutorial?

Comment: You have just provided JSON objects, where is your code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it!
I also found that jenkins API can create 1 json structure as I needed.
After I created the relevant json URL I read a lot about that and managed to read json URL and parse it.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        var USERNAME= 'elior';
        var PASSWORD = '3f800e'; // this isn't my real pass
        var store=''; 
        $.ajax
        ({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "http://bui-203.eu1.kokol.com:8080/job/ios_sdk/api/json?pretty=true&tree=name,description,builds[actions[parameters[name,value]],number,url,timestamp,result]",
                  dataType: 'json',
                  async: false,
                  headers: {
                    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD)
                  },
                  data: '{ "comment" }',
                  success: function (data){
                        for (var i=0 ; i< data.builds.length-1; i++ )
                        {
                                var rowclass="gradeX";
                                if( i % 2 == 0 ) 
                                        rowclass="gradeX";
                                else
                                        rowclass="gradeC";
                                store+='<tr class='+rowclass+'>';
                                        store+='<td>';
                                                store+=data.builds[i].timestamp; //timestamp
                                        store+='</td>';
                                        store+='<td>';
                                                store+=data.builds[i].actions[0].parameters[0].value; //Version
                                        store+='</td>';
                                        store+='<td>';
                                                store+=data.builds[i].number; //buildNumber
                                        store+='</td>';
                                        store+='<td>';
                                                store+=data.builds[i].actions[0].parameters[1].value; //IOS
                                        store+='</td>';
                                        store+='<td>';
                                                store+=data.builds[i].actions[0].parameters[2].value; //Cocoapods
                                        store+='</td>';
                                        store+='<td>';
                                                store+=data.builds[i].actions[0].parameters[3].value; //Unity
                                        store+='</td>';
                                        store+='<td>';
                                                store+=data.builds[3].actions[0].parameters[4].value; //Publish
                                        store+='</td>';
                                        store+='<td>';
                                                store+=data.builds[i].result; //result
                                        store+='</td>';
                                store+='</tr>';
                        }
                }
        });
        document.getElementById('id01').innerHTML=store;
        });
</script>
```